# Elasticsearch Marvel - Turn off logging

Tags: plugins, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

Is it possible to have Elasticsearch Marvel installed and have it not collect any data, would changing the template to 0 shards and 0 replicates do that for me?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just add this line to the `config/elasticsearch.yml` file to stop a node producing data:

```
marvel.agent.enabled: false
```

See the [configuration docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/marvel/current/index.html#_the_monitoring_cluster) for Marvel.

Comment: Didnt see this, thanks. Will mark correct when I can.

Comment: It actually changed in Elasticsearch 2 to `marvel.enabled: false` - `marvel.agent.enabled` does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
marvel.agent.interval: -1
```

Then restart ElasticSearch. From the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/configuration.html):

> *`marvel.agent.interval`
>   Controls how often data samples are collected. Defaults to 10s. **Set to -1 to temporarily disable data collection**. You can update this setting through the Cluster Update Settings API.*